# Any reason fb doesn't read meta tags for this share button?

Tags: facebook, share

I've looked through different posts here and couldn't find the answer..
check the source of http://he.thenamestork.com

```
<meta property="og:title" content="האתר שינחש את השם של תינוקך העתידי" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://he.thenamestork.com/gfx/FBthumb.png" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://he.thenamestork.com" />
```

this is generated by php. from some reason, fb totally ignores these meta tages when clicking share.
the WEIRED thing is - 
a. the exact same code worked just fine before
b. when clicking 'share' from he.thenamestork.com/names/something - the meta tags DOES get read by fb, even though both the meta tags and the share button are generated by the SAME PHP FILES and implemented in the SAME WAY.

what's wrong?

Comment: I've just tried to use a share button on your site and it's working as expected...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was facebook's cache of previous share properties. 
All I had to do was waiting.